# Problem htaccess and Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, .htaccess

I have a server with php4 and pho5 support.

But i need to user this one to say server it must be parsed like a php5 file

> AddType x-mapp-php5 .php .php5 .htm
>   .html

But now, my Zend Project have no access to the controllers...

> public/index/search -> 404 Not found

On my local Server it works perfectly.. someone know what to do?

my htaccess file

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development
AddType x-mapp-php5 .php .php5 .htm .html

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you not need something like this?

```
AddHandler php5-script .php
AddType text/html .php
```